# Dj-Stripe webhooks during localhost development

Tags: python, django, django-models, stripe-payments, webhooks

### Webhooks in local dev

I believe Dj-Stripe only creates DB entries for Charges and Invoices via webhooks -- correct me if I'm wrong. I'm currently using Customer.get_or_create, then doing customer.subscribe(plan_id). I've noticed this subscribes the customer but doesn't create any affiliated model entries such as charges and invoices.

In production, I know I can set up webhooks so that these entries are created, but is it possible during localhost (without some weird network forwarding things). I want my local dev environment to be as close to production, but obviously if I can't get these models being created it will be quite different.

### Subscribing customers (Solved)

Also, is there a better way to subscribe customers than having to use the deprecated settings plan_id? I'm currently doing a look-up in my settings with stripe_plan_id in order to find the correct settings plan_id to pass to customer.subscribe, I'm assuming this isn't the correct method.

Note: I'm on the 1.0.0 branch of dj-stripe.

Edit: I've seen I can just pass a Plan object in to customer.subscribe and it will retrieve the stripe_id itself. Just the webhooks question remaining!

Answer (score 0):

You should use https://ngrok.com on your local env to test webhooks.